# How do I talk to my teen daughter about her weight?

Tags: teen, weight

Over the past two years 17 year old daughter has gained about 60-70 lbs. Growing up she was always a healthy weight, however, by the end of her Junior year of high school she had visibly gained quite a bit of weight. She had stopped going to the gym, something she used to do at least 3x a week. At the time, I was hesitant to bring the subject up, as I hadn't noticed a change in her personality and she didn't seem concerned or bothered by the change.

Before the beginning of her senior year, I took her in for routine check up at the doctor. At the appointment,the doctor discussed the spike in her weight and informed her that her BMI ration was 25.6, which is clinically considered overweight. She seemed somewhat shocked at this and had little to say afterwords. I made an effort to cook healthier meals and encouraged her to go on runs with me, but she seemed uninterested.

She is now several months into her senior year and I am very worried about the toll her weight is taking on her health. She has gained around 20 lbs since her visit to the doctors office in July, and is resistant to discussing the issue in any way. I just want her to be happy, and I can see that she's unhappy with the change in her appearance and how she feels. She is very defensive when I try to talk to her about the subject, and her become more withdrawn from her family and friends.

Comment: I'm not  sure that this is just about weight.  Is it possible that there could be some sort of deeper issue at play here?

Comment: @Clay07g I fully agree with you. My question was whether or not she approaches her daughter in an open conversation kinda way or a "you're doing it wrong!" kinda way. My earlier comment was probably not clear in that regard. Most likely the daughter *knows* what she's doing wrong but as ajsmart is hinting there's probably a stronger hidden reason for it (for example, hormones changing/reached mental limit to compensate for lack of motivation/.... ). Removing my previous comment now as it's worded wrong anyway.

Comment: There are some good suggestions for talking to teens about weight here: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/34353/how-to-talk-to-a-teen-daughter-about-her-weight?rq=1